# types definition for mixin

Tags: typescript, vue.js

Hy guys, I have a typescript lib, and I want to write a type definition, for my button components this works:

```
 import { VueConstructor } from "vue";
 export const Button: VueConstructor;
```

But, how can I write a type definition for Mixins:

```
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
@Component
export default class TestMixin extends Vue {
  myVar = "";
}
```

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Create a `.d.ts` file with [type augmentations](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Augmenting-Types-for-Use-with-Plugins) that defines the props of your mixin:

*Vue 2:*

```js
import Vue from 'vue'

declare module 'vue/types/options' {
  interface ComponentOptions<V extends Vue> {
    myOption?: string
  }
}

export {}
```

*Vue 3:*

```js
declare module '@vue/runtime-core' {
  interface ComponentCustomProperties  {
    myOption?: string
  }
}

export {}
```

The `.d.ts` file should be located somewhere under `src/`. If using VS Code, make sure to restart the IDE to index the newly added `.d.ts` file.