# Vite/Vue3 OptionAPI mixin typings for props and head function with defineComponent

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, mixins, vuejs3-composition-api

I have a problem to type our custom plugins for a ts mixins in vue3.

We migrated our delivery from nuxt2/vue2 to vite/vue3.
Having all our components written for OptionAPI, we have some mixins.

Typing them looks quite simple in the documentation, just wrap it in `defineComponent()`.
To type our plugins we tried to pass an own type like `defineComponent<DefaultPageProperties>()`.

That helps with the plugins and also give us some vue component typings. The `defineComponent()` method decides if it is a Composition or an OptionApi mixin and in some cases it decides it's an `ComponentOptionsWithoutProps`. Even if there are props! Is there a way to detect props and the head functions automatically without defining them again? Props work with just `defineComponent()` but we can't use our plugins in those mixins anymore.

The bare minimum of our mixin looks like the following and still won't detect that there are props:

```js
videoPlayerMixin = defineComponent<DefaultPageProperties>({
    props: {
        videoData: {
            type: Object,
            default: () => null,
        },
    },
})
```

The Type looks like (just changed own types to any .. dont worry):

```js
import { DefineComponent } from 'vue'
export type DefaultPageProperties = DefineComponent & {
    $mobileHeaderIsSet: boolean
    $route: any
}
```

Are we on the right track and how to type it properly to work with props and the vue2 head function. Or is there a different way to type our plugins and just use `defineComponent()` as it is?

The Error messages with the type given to `defineComponent()`:

> The expected type comes from property 'props' which is declared here on type 'ComponentOptionsWithoutProps<DefaultPageProperties, {}, {}, {}, {}, ComponentOptionsMixin, ComponentOptionsMixin, {}, string, {}, string, ComponentPublicInstanceConstructor<...> & ... 5 more ... & {}>'

We also tried to define the props by our own but it do not change anything to the Error:

```js
type Props = {
    type:
        | BooleanConstructor
        | ObjectConstructor
        | ArrayConstructor
        | StringConstructor
        | NumberConstructor
        | null;
    default?: boolean | object | any[] | string | number | null;
}
export type DefaultPageProperties = DefineComponent & {
    $mobileHeaderIsSet: boolean
    $route: RouteData
    props: Record<string, Props>
}
```

We tried to declare it, but may we need another utility class, because the mixins won't know about our plugins that way: (without the DefaultPageProperties)
(like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66478550/types-definition-for-mixin/66481195#66481195))

```js
declare module '@vue/runtime-core' {
    interface ComponentCustomProperties {
        $mobileHeaderIsSet: boolean;
        $route: any;
    }
}
```